# Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, updates

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action_t']))
{

    $gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
    $firstname=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $sellers=$_REQUEST['sellers'];
    $company=$_REQUEST['company'];


    echo $query=" update register set `name`='$gender' , `f_name`='$firstname' , `l_name`='$lastname' ,`sellers` ='$sellers' ,`company`='$company' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    //die();
    echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Updated Your account') </script>";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['action_p']))
{

    $existing_password=$_REQUEST['existing_password'];
    $npassword=$_REQUEST['npassword'];
    $w=mysql_query("select password from register where id='$id'");
    $ro=mysql_fetch_array($w);
    $password=$ro['password'];
    if($existing_password==$password)
    {
    echo $queryi="UPDATE `register` SET `password`='$npassword' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($queryi)or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Updated Password') </script>";
    }
    else 
    echo "<script>alert('You have Enter Wrong Password') </script>";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['action_e']))
{

    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $existing_password=$_REQUEST['existing_password'];
    $w=mysql_query("select password from register where id='$id'");
    $ro=mysql_fetch_array($w);
    $password=$ro['password'];
    if($existing_password==$password)
    {
    echo $querye="UPDATE `register` SET `email`='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($querye)or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Updated Email') </script>";
    }
    else 
     echo "<script>alert('You have Enter Wrong Password') </script>";
}
 ?>
```

My query result 
update register set `name`='m' , `f_name`='dsf' , `l_name`='dfsf' ,`sellers` ='Consumer' ,`company`='fdafa' WHERE id='3

when execute this query in sql it works fine but in my php file it gives me error Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'  . I have check my column name already it is right. Meanwhile i change code placement then error is same but column name changed like 
Unknown column 'f_name' in 'field list'. And secondly my others queries executing successfully but not effect my data base. Also these queries are working fine in mysql.

Comment: Could you directly connect to your mysql database, and edit your answer to include the output of this command:  DESCRIBE register;

Comment: i made sure about that i m quite sure because  i know error when mysql database isn't connected  .

Comment: Note that you are **wonderfully** open to [SQL Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710).  Please use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), or you risk having your database exported/box taken over by _automated tools_.

Comment: i think you have hint about my error . Thanks let me try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using the wrong table/database in PHP?

```
echo "<pre>", var_dump( mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") ) ) , "</pre>"
```

Is the table in the output? If so, is the column in the next output?

```
echo "<pre>", var_dump( mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM register") ) ) , "</pre>"
```

Comment: array (size=1)
  'Tables_in_fashion' => string 'admin' (length=5)

array (size=6)
  'Field' => string 'id' (length=2)
  'Type' => string 'int(11)' (length=7)
  'Null' => string 'NO' (length=2)
  'Key' => string 'PRI' (length=3)
  'Default' => null
  'Extra' => string 'auto_increment' (length=14)                             this is the result can you explain it ?

Comment: @HassanAli Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: thanks i sorted out my error and also had  solved it .